# 32 bit pointer in a 64 bit Solaris compile

Tags: c++

I know this is a strange questions but I was wondering if it was possible to make a 32 bit pointer in 64 bit compile on Solaris using g++.  The final object would need to be 64 bit however one of my pointers offsets is becomming larger on Solaris then it is in windows if I do use 64 bit to compile.  This is causing a big problem.  I was wondering if it was possible to make a 32bit pointer within my 64 bit compiled object.

Comment: You should modify the question to talk about what you really want to do - there may be a better way than relying on pointer sizes being the same between platforms. Describe the goal, not the step (http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal).

Comment: There's a lack of specifics in this question that makes it hard to answer.  What is the "big problem"?  How is it that you prevent pointer offsets from getting large in 64-bit windows?  Even the first part of your question doesn't make much sense "is it possible to make a 32-bit pointer in 64-bit compile" ... I can't figure out what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer size is a property of your target architecture, so you cannot mix and match 32- and 64-bit pointers. I would strongly suggest re-thinking your design (which smells like usual mistake of casting pointers to integers and back.) You can theoretically work with "limited-reach" offsets, but again please ask yourself why, and what would be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change regular pointers, the size of a pointer is `sizeof(void *)`. And if you could, what would you do with an 32bit pointer on an 64bit system?

Do you mean pointers in C or do you maybe mean pointers to a file offset?

Answer (score 0):

If you have pointer type there, then you shouldn't make it 32-bit in 64-bit program. If it is just some offset that not related to memory model, then you could use different type with stable size across platforms, something like `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to "need" a 32 bit pointer on a 64 bit machine.  I also dont understand this line:

> The final object would need to be 64 bit however

I would take a closer look and try to fix the bug on your end.  If you post some example code we may be able to help more.